# How to add extra visible space after UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

I made a 4x25 UIButton grid system for a collection view:

```
    @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UICollectionView* collectionView;
```

When I scroll vertically down, I reach the last section and the bottom portions of the buttons are cut off.  I have to really scroll down (past where the bottom of the screen stops) to see the rest of the buttons.

I ran into the same problem with UIScrollView and viewing text.  I used the following line to fix it (just adding 30 points to the y-dimension).

```
    theScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(theScroll.contentSize.width, CGRectGetMaxY(label.frame)+30.0f);
```

Would I do something similar with 'collectionView' property?  If so, how would I do it?  (theScroll, in the above code, is a UIScrollView instance).

Comment: to set autolayout constraint for  collectionview

Comment: try disabling pagination from storyboard for the UICollectionView

Comment: please see my answer @Frank

Comment: Try providing autoresizingMask mask to all your views

Answer (score 1):

`UICollectionView` layouts are managed by certain properties and not `autolayout`.

You can achieve what you want by adjusting these properties, such as:

- `cell size`
- `header size`
- `footer size`
- `minimum inter item line and cell spacing`
- `section insets`

You can also use the appropriate delegate methods to set these properties. 
Of course `autolayout` is required to hold the collection cell in a superview and the contents of the collection view cell, but the scroll content size is decided by the above mentioned values.

Please go through the [apple documentation on collection views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/). 
Hope this helps :)!

Answer (score 0):

Use below method and try maybe it will helped you

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int width = ((self.collectionView.frame.size.width)/3)-2;//set width value according to your UICollectionViewCell design 
    return CGSizeMake(width, width);
}
```

It's UICollectionView delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Hope u gave the size of the collectionview correctly